# Sending Bitmap to Server (B2) via POST not working OKhttpClient HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection, backblaze

I am using Backblaze and managed to upload files (images and videos) to my buckets in my iOS App (swift 5) but I am unable to do so in my java android app.

I receive the correct auth token, download url, upload url and API Url.

But when I try to post it to that url its not working and I receive the following error

```
W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
D/yyyy enclosed: saveImgToStorage:     buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource@e5232ab).inputStream()
saveImgToStorage: 401
W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after response has been read
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.flax.de.Helper.StorageService.saveImgToStorage(StorageService.java:192)
    at com.flax.de.Helper.StorageService.getUploadUrl(StorageService.java:142)
    at com.flax.de.Helper.StorageService.getAuthData(StorageService.java:95)
W/System.err:     at com.flax.de.Categories.NewPostFragment$3.run(NewPostFragment.java:341)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The function trying to post the data to the upload url is the following

```
   static private void saveImgToStorage(Context context, String id, String uploadUrl, String uploadAuthorizationToken
        , String downloadUrl, Uri imageUrl, String bucketName, Interfaces.OnSuccessHashMap onSuccess
        , Interfaces.OnError onError) throws IOException {

    String photoUrl = downloadUrl+"/file/"+bucketName+"/"+id;
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
    hashMap.put(API.databaseStrings.URL, photoUrl);
    Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), imageUrl);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] fileData = baos.toByteArray();
    String contentType = "image/jpg";
    String sha1 = "do_not_verify";



    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", uploadAuthorizationToken);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Bz-File-Name", id);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Bz-Content-Sha1", sha1);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        Log.d("yyyy enclosed", "saveImgToStorage: " + connection.getErrorStream().toString());
        Log.d("yyyy enclosed", "saveImgToStorage: " + connection.getResponseCode());

        DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(fileData);
        String jsonResponse = myInputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);


        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        onError.onError();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Error code is as you see

> 401

I have no idea why its not working.
As I said it is working perfectly fine on my iOS devices which uses basically the same code only written in swift (taken from the guide from back blaze)
I personally think its not an issue from back blaze but rather that my request is wrong?
Or the format of my bitmap?

Or maybe I have to do it asynchronously? I tried it with a thread before move it out from the main thread but it did not work either.

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://pod-000-1070-11.backblaze.com/b2api/v2/b2_upload_file/afec4cd53b2f323f715a0c18/c000_v0001070_t0002
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
```

is what I receive if use this code

```
      String photoUrl = downloadUrl+"/file/"+bucketName+"/"+id;
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
    hashMap.put(API.databaseStrings.URL, photoUrl);
    Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), imageUrl);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] fileData = baos.toByteArray();
    String contentType = "image/jpg";
    String sha1 = "do_not_verify";

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String json = null;


    try {
        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", uploadAuthorizationToken);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Bz-File-Name", id);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Bz-Content-Sha1", sha1);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(fileData);
        String jsonResponse = myInputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: `Sending Bitmap to Server` You should not send bitmaps to your server but image files like .jpg or .png.

Comment: I guess you did not read through my post. I made a byteArray out of my bitmap.

Comment: Yes i saw that. But that byte array contains the bytes for a .jpeg. It is not relevant that it comes from a bitmap. You are trying to upload jpeg bytes. You could have filled that byte arrray also from the bytes of a jpg file. Look at the subject of your post as it does not cover what you do.

Comment: However, its not working anyway so I am looking for help to solve it

Comment: Sorry but i cannot give help for sending bitmaps to a server. ;-)

Comment: The request does not work. Thats what I need to fix first

Comment: It makes no sense to fix your subject afterwards.

Comment: My question is clear: I want to upload a selected bitmap to a server via a http request. There is no need to change my subject as it stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the first version of the function is these two lines:

```java
Log.d("yyyy enclosed", "saveImgToStorage: " + connection.getErrorStream().toString());
Log.d("yyyy enclosed", "saveImgToStorage: " + connection.getResponseCode());
```

Both `getErrorStream()` and `getResponseCode()` cause the request to be sent, and the response to be read, since you've asked for the error response and response code from the server. `connection.getOutputStream()` throws an error because it's too late to send the request body.

You should remove these lines, or move them after the line:

```java
writer.write(fileData);
```

`HttpURLConnection` is 'broken by design' in the way that it implicitly sends the request when you try to read the response.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed It ling ago but may be interesting for others.

Comment: @Zash__ Great - could you mark it as correct to help others? Thanks!